# MDF file dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a folder with 3 MDF files, I need attach them, but they all have NDF files, how to know which NDF files are next to the MDF, using TSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not do this, you need to know the database beforehand to get the files restored correctly

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching just an MDF.  If they're in the same folder path they were created in, the MDF will find it's corresponding NDF(s) on it's own.  If not, it should throw an error which may (not sure) indicate which NDF it's looking for.

Comment: Yes, it throws an error, but this approach is not valid for my application. I'm creating a C # script, and they're all in the same directory, capturing this because the exception would be too labor-intensive and unreliable, needs a list of NDFs from an MDF to merge everything into a query to attach

Comment: @ArthNRick Does the error indicate which NDF it is looking for? if so, then you could trap the error and parse out the filename and then re-attach with the correct NDF name.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to identify the main file (mdf) from a ndf, or vice versa without using an exception, something serious little performance, I changed my logic so that the files are grouped by folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from sys.sysfiles
```

Comment: The mdf file is not yet part of the server, needs to be attached to the server, and knows what the ndf files are